# How to remove extra column in SSDT designer

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools

I am using SSDT in Visual studio 2017 community. I am having an extra column in my designer. Anyone knows what's it and how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the new area for laying out your parameters.

You can change the size of the parameters pane by dragging the dividing line between that and the main design area.

But if you want to get rid of it, you can go to the Report menu in the Visual Studio menu bar, choose 'View' and then deselect 'Parameters'.

Comment: Thank you @Rich. I have been wondering what is that lately since it is not included in other versions of Visual Studio that I was working with.